# SQL job to ALTER VIEW

Tags: t-sql, view, conditional-statements, alter

On a weekly base, data is updated from a source into one of the two identical tables: Table_ODD or Table_EVEN. A view transfers data from the active table to a reporting tool. Which table is currently active is stored in a table.
So the view is either like this:

```
Create View [dbo].[V_ReportData] AS SELECT *    FROM [Table_ODD]  -- for odd-week
```

or

```
Create View [dbo].[V_ReportData] AS SELECT *    FROM [Table_EVEN] -- for even-week
```

The switch may only be performed after approval of the updated data, and will be done by an administrator 
 who will manually start the job.
I had like to create a job that will do the switch. I have tried this code:`

```
Declare  @NumberOfTables as int
        ,@ActiveTable    as nvarchar(100);

Set  @NumberOfTables = (Select Count(*) from [Table_Status] where Upper([Status]) = 'ACTIVE' ) ;
if   @NumberOfTables = 1
  BEGIN
    Set  @ActiveTable = (Select UPPER([TABLE_NAME])  from [Table_Status] where Upper([Status]) = 'ACTIVE' );    
  END;

if @ActiveTable = 'TABLE_EVEN'
BEGIN 
    ALTER View [dbo].[V_TABLE_] AS
        SELECT  *  
        FROM [dbo].[TABLE_ODD]

    UPDATE [Table_Status]
        Set [STATUS] = 'ACTIVE' 
        Where  [TABLE_NAME]   = 'TABLE_ODD'
    UPDATE [Table_Status]
        Set [STATUS] = 'PASSIVE' 
        Where  [TABLE_NAME]   = 'TABLE_EVEN'
END

if @ActiveTable = 'TABLE_ODD'
BEGIN 
    ALTER View [dbo].[V_TABLE_] AS
        SELECT  *  
        FROM [dbo].[TABLE_EVEN]

    UPDATE [Table_Status]
        Set [STATUS] = 'ACTIVE' 
        Where  [TABLE_NAME]   = 'TABLE_EVEN'
    UPDATE [Table_Status]
        Set [STATUS] = 'PASSIVE' 
        Where  [TABLE_NAME]   = 'TABLE_ODD'
END
`
```

But The ALTER VIEW statement may not be included in any part of the coding.
So I think the ALTER VIEW  statement should be in a separate step.
But that step must be activated conditionaly, namely based on the condition which table is active.
In short something like this:

```
    if @ActiveTable = 'TABLE_EVEN'
then step 2
else step 3
```

DROP and CREATE view is not recommended because of authorizations that are granted to the view. With a DROP VIEW statement, all authorizations are drop as well.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you considered defining the view to use the correct table all of the time? Something like `select * from Table_Even where DateDiff( week, '2020-01-05', GetDate() ) % 2 = 0 union all select * from Table_Odd where DateDiff( week, '2020-01-05', GetDate() ) % 2 = 1;`. You can jiggle the base date to make the correct week odd or even.

Comment: Hello HABO. Thanks for the suggestion, but in this case it is not a matter of odd or even week data. The data from the source is updated on a week base. The data is from running contracts since Jan 2020 and is progressively growing with the number of transport days over time. Each week a validation has to be done on the new loaded data before reporting is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I took me a little while , but found the answer!
I had to create multiple steps first, before I could switch to the specific job step based on an error-code. 
[List of job steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxand.png)

step 1: check if switch is valid, e.g. only one table is Active and DateTimeStamp of passive table (which should be the last updated) is more recent then active table

```
    Declare     @NumberOfTables as int
    ,@ActiveTable    as nvarchar(100)
    ,@Update_DateTime_Active  as datetime
    ,@Update_DateTime_Passive  as datetime;
Set  @NumberOfTables = (Select Count(*) from [Table_Status] where Upper([Status]) = 'ACTIVE' ) ;
if @NumberOfTables = 1
  BEGIN
    set @Update_DateTime_Active = (Select [UPDATED]  from [Table_Status] where Upper([Status]) = 'ACTIVE' );
    set @Update_DateTime_Passive = (Select [UPDATED]  from [Table_Status] where Upper([Status]) <> 'ACTIVE' );
  END

IF @Update_DateTime_Active > @Update_DateTime_Passive
RAISERROR ('Status Active table not compatible with Update DateTimestamp',16,2)

if @NumberOfTables <> 1
RAISERROR ('Tables Data_ODD and Data_EVEN have same status',16,3)
```

Step 2: determin which table is currently active

```
    Declare     @NumberOfTables as int
    ,@ActiveTable    as nvarchar(100);

Set  @NumberOfTables = (Select Count(*) from [Table_Status] where Upper([Status]) = 'ACTIVE' ) ;

if @NumberOfTables = 1
  BEGIN
    Set  @ActiveTable = (Select UPPER([TABLE_NAME])  from [Data_Table_Status] where Upper([Status]) = 'ACTIVE' );   
  END

if @ActiveTable = 'DATA_EVEN'
BEGIN 
    RAISERROR('Now switch VIEW to table ...ODD',1,1)    
END
```

This step determin the next step to be taken in the advanced settings of the step:
On succes action: goto step 3
on Error action: goto step 5 
Remember: when ..EVEN is active, an error is raised, causing the job to go to step 5 (which is activating ..ODD)

Step 3: alter view to EVEN
`ALTER View [dbo].[V_Data_] AS  SELECT  *  FROM [dbo].[Data_EVEN]`

step 4: updated status table (change status of ODD to Active, and EVEN to Passive)

```
UPDATE [Data_Table_Status]
    Set [STATUS] = 'ACTIVE' 
    Where  [TABLE_NAME]   = 'Data_EVEN'

UPDATE [Data_Table_Status]
    Set [STATUS] = 'PASSIVE' 
    Where  [TABLE_NAME]   = 'Data_ODD'
```

Step 5: alter view to ODD
step 6: updated status table (change status of ODD to Active, and EVEN to Passive)